# How to take in user input and print out details

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm working on an exam app (c# console application)

The app asks the user to enter its name, I would like the app to read in that user's name and 
print the user's details based on the details I've stored in the objects

For example:
If the user's name matches the name in this object:

```
students s3 = new students("Dee", "Scott", "Computing", 100m, 66.6m);
```

how could it print this user's details.

I've got a separate method that prints out the user's details

```
public string gradeDetails {
        get { return FirstName + LastName + Course + FinalGrade; }
    }
```

I cant figure out how to match the user input to corresponding object.

Comment: You need to add all your `student` objects to a common data structure so you can iterate through them and compare names to the one inputted from the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Console.Readline()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
   public static void Main()
   {
      string line;
      Console.WriteLine("Enter one or more lines of text (press CTRL+Z to exit):");
      Console.WriteLine();
      do { 
         Console.Write("   ");
         line = Console.ReadLine();
         if (line != null) 
            Console.WriteLine("      " + line);
      } while (line != null);
```

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow but this seems to happen on occasion.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(); or Console.Write();
```

I am not sure if that is what you are asking, but those are the calls to read and write.

This info is easily Google-able though.

Answer (score 0):

The example below will do what you asked for. If you have any questions regarding the code I used then don't hesitate to ask.

```
class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Course { get; set; }
    public decimal FinalGrade { get; set; }

    public Student(string firstName,
                   string lastName,
                   string course)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Course = course;
        FinalGrade = 0;
    }

    // This will first call the constructor above and then continue.
    public Student(string firstName,
                   string lastName,
                   string course,
                   decimal finalGrade) : this(firstName, lastName, course)
    {
        FinalGrade = finalGrade;
    }

    // By overriding ToString we can use Console.WriteLine(student) directly.
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format(@"FirstName: {0}, LastName: {1}, Course: {2}, FinalGrade: {3}",
                             FirstName,
                             LastName,
                             Course,
                             FinalGrade);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create our students.
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>
                                 {
                                     new Student("John", "Test", "Computing"),
                                     new Student("Tim", "Test", "Computing", 8.25m)
                                 };

        string user = "";
        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of the student:");
            user = Console.ReadLine();
            if (user.Equals("exit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                break;

            // Find the student or return null.
            Student student = students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.FirstName.Equals(user, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

            if (student != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Student info:");
                Console.WriteLine(student);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Student '" + user + "' not found.");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Wait until a key is pressed.
            Console.WriteLine("Press a key to continue..");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:
create a class called Student:

```
 public class Student
    {
        public string Fname { get; set; }
        public string LName { get; set; }
        public string Course { get; set; }
        public string FinalGrade { get; set; }

    }
```

Then do this

```
class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {



            Console.WriteLine("Enter you name:");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine(gradeDetails(name));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static string gradeDetails(string name)
        {
             List<Student> students = new List<Student>()
                {
                    new Student{ Fname = "Scott",LName ="Dee",Course = "Computing", FinalGrade = "66.66m"},
                    new Student{Fname = "Joe",LName = "Don",Course = "Chemestry", FinalGrade = "80.77m"}
                };

            var student = students.SingleOrDefault(s => s.LName.ToLower() == name.ToLower());

            if (student!=null)
            {
                return student.Fname + "" + student.LName + "" + student.Course + "" + student.FinalGrade;
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ask user to enter name and print name**

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace stackoverflow1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string name;

                Console.WriteLine("Enter your name : ");
                name = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Hello " + name + " , Welcome to OOP!");

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```